# using libfmt to format to a string

Tags: c++, fmt

using libfmt to print to a file is very convenient:

```
auto file = fmt::output_file(filename);
file.print(...);
```

But how can I format to a memory buffer, ultimatiley converting to a string? I would imagine something like

```
auto buf = some_buffer_object{};
buf.print(...);
std::string s = buf.get_string();
```

But I can find no such buffer type in the documentation (`fmt::memory_buffer` seems related, but does not work like this).

Important: I need multiple calls to `print`, so `auto s = fmt::format(...)` is not an option.

Comment: Although not as nice to use as `buf.print(...)`, but [`fmt::format_to`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html?highlight=format_to#_CPPv4I0DpEN3fmt9format_toE8OutputIt8OutputIt13format_stringIDp1TEDpRR1T) could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I format to a memory buffer, ultimatiley converting to a string?

Use `format_to` and print to an iterator the appends to a string.

Comment: indeed, `std::string s; fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(s), ...)` works. Somewhat more verbose than I expected, but does the job for me.